# Connection closed prematurely Tomcat 7.0.52

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to fix a bug in a web application that has cropped up since we upgraded from Tomcat 6.0.26 to 7.0.52. The application is basically a proxy that gets content from another web site, the offending code follows:

```
public static synchronized void connect(String externalServiceUrl, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    log.info("Connecting to " + externalServiceUrl);
    URLConnection serverConnection = new URL(externalServiceUrl).openConnection();
    serverConnection.setDoInput(true);
    serverConnection.setDoOutput(false);

    Map responseMap = serverConnection.getHeaderFields();
    for (Iterator iterator = responseMap.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();

        List values = (List) responseMap.get(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            Object o = values.get(i);
            response.setHeader(key, o.toString());
        }
    }

    OutputStream toClient = response.getOutputStream();

    try {
        BufferedInputStream fromServer = new   BufferedInputStream(serverConnection.getInputStream());

        int bytie;
        try {
            while ((bytie = fromServer.read()) != -1) {
                toClient.write(bytie); // Exception thrown from here
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fromServer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.severe("Cannot connect to external service with URL " + externalServiceUrl);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally   {
        toClient.flush();
        toClient.close();
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeByte(OutputBuffer.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:203)
    at nz.cri.gns.boardaccess.proxy.ProxyHelper.connect(ProxyHelper.java:72)

...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

Which might normally indicate the user has navigated away from the page causing the browser to close the connection, but this isn't the case. I've tested in Chrome, IE8 and Firefox all with the same result - a "web page is not available" message on the browser and the above stack trace on the server. The `toClient.write(bytie);` line is normally executed 20k+ times, so around half the file is being written to the response before the connection is closed. This happens in less than a second, so it's unlikely to be caused by Tomcat's connectionTimeout setting (set at the default of 20000ms).

Comment: so this code does not depend on Tomcat does it.  Have you tried moving this code out to a standalone app?  Do the same problems exist?

Comment: Also why use a BufferedInputStream and then only read one byte at a time - sounds slow.

Comment: The code doesn't necessarily depend on Tomcat, but that's our standard container in production so I need a solution that works in that. Rolling the Tomcat version back to 6.0.26 resolves the issue. Regarding the way the BufferedInputStream is used...not sure, I didn't write it. There's a number of ways the code could be tidied up a bit but I just want to fix the main problem first. Thanks for your suggestions.